# Strings in C Program

Tags: c

I am making a program in C language which prints the **ASCII** value of the string/text **including spaces**. The program works fine and give exact ASCII values of string including spaces but the problem is that it also prints '10' at the end of all ASCII values.

This is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
    {
       char str[100];
       int i;
       printf("Enter a string: ");
       fgets(str,100,stdin); 
       //scanf("%s",str);
       printf("String is: %s\n",str);
       printf("ASCII value in Decimal is: ");
      for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
             printf("%d ",str[i]);
          }
          printf("\n");
    getch();
}
```

Please help me out, tell me what's the problem and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `10` is a newline-character.

Comment: It is time to read the [man page for `fgets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx) which says *"... The newline character, if read, is included in the string.*"

Comment: thnx @xing it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a string with `fgets` the enter you press is included in the string( [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgets&sektion=3) ). ASCII code for `\n` is  `10`.